# Contest to predict date and time that Marc Gravell will eclipse 100k

Tags: discussion, contest

Now that our [Jon Skeet contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4255/contest-to-predict-date-and-time-that-jon-skeet-will-eclipse-100k) is over. I'd like to try our hand again but this time with Marc Gravell. When do you think he'll surpass the 100,000 mark?

[Current Score http://www.grumpydev.com/imageFlair/imageFlair.php?userid=23354](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/07/11/stack-overflow-share-your-flair-now-in-png/)

Comment: To confirm, the final date was the 19th.

Comment: big congrats to you Marc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**December 19, 2009**

I know... I'm a big cheater :p

Comment: pah! Just for that I'm tempted to suspend my own account, so I don't gain any rep tomorrow!

Comment: We double-dog-dare you.

Comment: congrats to Even Mien for answering correctly... even if he answered it the day the Marc crossed the finish line.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I'm ~81k now, after *roughly* a year (less a few days) - so add ~3 months. I'll say Dec 15th.

Comment: Wow.  It's mildly humiliating to those of us that have been around since beta that neither you nor Jon are Yearlings yet.  I doff my top hat to both of you.

Comment: I call shenanigans! Can't bet on yourself.

Comment: I can too ;-p Plus: if I get there too early I can always suspend myself so I don't go over-rep ahead of time. I'm not sure that I **will** though...

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Are you saying that Jon Skeet joined after me?

Comment: @Ikke: Jon joined SO four days after you (he gets his Yearling badge tomorrow).  Don't feel bad, though.  I had a forty-day head start on Jon, and he passed me like I was standing still.

Comment: Right now, looks like it'll be Dec 19th.

Comment: Well, 4 days in a 3 month guess isn't too terrible...

Comment: I was just going to add "good guess", but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: @Marc: Are you this good at estimating when you'll finish a project? ;-)

Comment: @Dexter - I'll let you know when one is "finished". 11 years into pro development, and the only way I've found to *fully* "finish" a project is to change jobs.

Answer (score 3):

In six to eight weeks

Or, as a real entry into the contest, Dec 23.

Comment: you forgot the "to eight" part...

Comment: Hmmm... ~445/day - sounds like a lot of fun ;-p

Comment: @tvanfosson: touche

Comment: @Marc: c'mon, man of yer caliber? :)

Comment: @Squillman, you could still get it right if you furiously downvote Mark for the next couple of days ;-)

Comment: Hey! Play fair! Where's that "delete user" button...

Comment: Haha, let's see.  30 votes at 2/vote x 5 days = 300 points, if I do it spaced out enough to trick the auto rep fixer.  Hmmm.  Nah :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is Dec 12th, 2009

Answer (score 0):

The progression of his reputation is exponential, so I'll guess earlier. I'll say November 2nd.

Comment: I don't see any evidence for that... slightly sub-linear at the moment, if anything.

Comment: Perhaps it is because of the reputation cap.

Comment: Is there a consolation prize for the first loser?

Answer (score 0):

November 29, 2009

Answer (score 0):

December 5th, 2pm UTC.

Comment: You could be a bit more specific perhaps?

Comment: Looks like I missed it by a hair. Currently he's at 96,785...